# Compose an interface of several generic interfaces

Tags: java

```
public interface Visitor<T> {
    public void visit(T t);
}

interface VisitorCompany extends Visitor<Employee>, Visitor<Company>,
        Visitor<Department>;
```

I assume something like this is not possible in java?

Comment: Even if it were possible, I wouldn't recommend it, at least not in the context that you present it in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible in java due to type erasure. please refer here [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) for the explanation of type erasure.